# Calculating a probability with the hypergeometric distribution

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

I'm studying the hypergeometric distribution with the probability mass function
$$
Pr(X=k) = \frac{{K \choose k}{(N-K) \choose (n-k)}}{{N \choose n}},
$$
where $N$ is the population size, $K$ is the number of success states in the population, $n$ is the number of draws, and $k$ is the number of observed successes.

Suppose we have $K=N/2$ (assume that $N$ is even and that $n$ is divisible by $4$).
I've been trying to get a simplified expression for getting at least $n/4$ successes.
I get
$$
Pr(X \ge n/4)
= 1 - Pr(X < n/4)
= 1 - \sum_{\ell=0}^{n/4-1} \frac{{K \choose \ell}{(N-K) \choose (n-\ell)}}{{N \choose n}}.
$$
Is there any combinatorial identity that I could use for further simplifying this expression?